# Update and delete data in database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, json

I use **codeigniter**. i have following values as json_encode in database row, i want delete value `3` in row 1 and values `14` & `5` in database table.

DELETE -> value `3` on row 1 & values `14`, `5` on rows 2
UPDATE -> value `2` to `8` on row 1 & value `3` to `17` on rows 2.

How is query it for values json?

Row 1:

```
id=1

[{
    "hotel_id": ["3"]
}, {
    "hotel_id": ["2"]
}, {
    "hotel_id": ["1"]
}]
```

Row 2:

```
id=2

[{
    "hotel_id": ["14"]
}, {
    "hotel_id": ["5"]
}, {
    "hotel_id": ["4"]
}, {
    "hotel_id": ["3"]
}, {
    "hotel_id": ["2"]
}, {
    "hotel_id": ["1"]
}]
```

Comment: Don't store JSON in a database as text then hope the DB can magically figure out how to do anything with it.

Comment: I was wondering how long it would take for someone to say "mongo" without knowing anything about the data or the user's requirements ...

Comment: Did can not delete and update data(array) json in database?

Comment: Wait, is he actually saving JSON in DB as text?!

Comment: I store data(values) with json_encode in one row from database table.

Comment: Well, you can delete a row in the database, not a value in a row. To work on values, you may connect to the database with a language, read the row, modify its contents and update the db. What language are you using ?

Comment: +1 to balance some down votes. I don't think this is a bad question, it's just bad practice and we're all learning here. Better explain why it is bad practice than down vote I think.

Comment: I'm going to leave this open as a useful lesson to others on "how not to". To the OP, why is your data stored as json in your database?

Answer (score 1):

What most of the commenters are trying to say is that your problem is a very common one when storing serialized data in the DB (like JSON strings) - That is exactly why this is considered bad practice. 
All the wonderful tools of relational databases, like indexing, sorting, grouping and querying according to any column are gone once the data is stored as a big pile of characters the DB can't parse.

The solution is to save the actual DATA in the DB, and format it as JSON only on the application side, for use when needed. 
In your case, you can create a table like hotels_to_users (I am doing some guesswork here about the meaning of your data, hoping you get it even if it's not exactly what you need). This table will look like:

```
user_id (?) |  hotel_id
1           |  1
1           |  2
2           |  14
```

This will make it very easy to query, update, insert and delete any specific hotel to any user.

Hope this makes sense and that you are able to make that change, otherwise your problem can be solved with either some MySQL string functions like REPLACE and SUBSTR, or by doing all the work in the application code and saving a new JSON when done.  Either way, maintaining it will be hard and require more effort in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Storing data as json_encode is really a bad choice since you can't do anything trough sql with them.

You have to take your data, read it (json_decode), do stuff with php and then replace the new data with a new json_encode. Really bad.

Think changing the way you store that values. Maybe a support table.