# Update json in database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, json

I want comparison between two table (`table_foreign`, `table_submits`) in database that if not existing some data from table `table_foreign` in table `table_submits`  on  database, deletded it data in table `table_foreign`  or updated.

```
$query_tfhi = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_foreign ORDER BY id desc");
foreach ($query_tfhi->result() as $row) {
    $data_hi = json_decode($row->how_id, true);
    foreach ($data_hi as $hitf) {
        foreach ($hitf['howinto_id'] as $val_hitf) {
            //echo $val_hitf.'<br>';

            $query_delhi = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_submits WHERE id LIKE '$val_hitf'");
            if ($query_delhi->num_rows() == 0) {
                //echo $val_hitf;
                $this->db->query("DELETE how_id = array('howinto_id'=>$val_hitf) FROM tour_foreign WHERE id LIKE '$row->id'");
            } else {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have in table `table_foreign` on column `how_id` as(this data store(inserted) with `json_encode` on a column in row database table):

```
[{
    "howinto_id": ["14"]
},{
    "howinto_id": ["5"]
},{
    "howinto_id": ["4"]
}, {
    "howinto_id": ["3"]
}, {
    "howinto_id": ["2"]
}, {
    "howinto_id": ["1"]
}]
```

in table `table_submits` on column `id`:

`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`

With comparison between two table in `table_foreign` value `14,`5` should deleted. after this it is as:

```
[{
    "howinto_id": ["4"]
}, {
    "howinto_id": ["3"]
}, {
    "howinto_id": ["2"]
}, {
    "howinto_id": ["1"]
}]
```

In output above PHP code have error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>  Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '('howinto_id'=>14) FROM tour_foreign WHERE id LIKE '1'' at line
>   1
>
> DELETE how_id = array('howinto_id'=>14) FROM table_foreign WHERE id
>   LIKE '1'
>
> Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

How can fix they?

Comment: PHP is PHP, and SQL is SQL. Don't mix the two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update and delete data in database mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625055/update-and-delete-data-in-database-mysql)

Comment: This comparison (operation) How do I?

Comment: Why are you inserting JSON into MySQL in the first place? This is [bad design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364803/storing-arrays-in-the-database/7364834#7364834)

Comment: Do you want to compare against an element of a JSON value in a table? That's not possible, at least not any sane way.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think your problem should be fixed like this:

1. First , you need to retrieve data of two tables as arrays (anyhow) from json obj as it returns array
2. Second you can use 
    `array_diff($array1 , $array2)`
   which returns array of differences between those tow arrays
3. Third you can select Ids from the difference array ( `$ids` )

   and use

   `$this->db->where_in("Id",$ids)->delete("table_submits")`

Like this you have deleted the diff between the tow tables from the database , and tell me if this is ok with you